# Power analysis for serial multiple mediation

Tags: spss, statistical-power, mediation

Does anyone have suggested methods for running a power analysis for a serial multiple mediation model? I am running the model in SPSS with the PROCESS macro. G*power does not appear to have the capacity to run a power analyses for a multiple mediation model, wherein the mediators are sequential.

Comment: What inference will you draw from such a model?

Comment: If you use bootstrap this is probably the right paper to read: Zhang Z. Monte Carlo based statistical power analysis for mediation models: methods and software. Behavior Research Methods, 2014;46:1184-98